# C++ / Objective-C : The two files of a class are called Header and ...?

Tags: c++, objective-c

In languages like C++ or Objective-C a class normally consist of two files. The first is called Header or Interface but what is the "official" name of the other file?

In some books it's just called "Codefile" in other "implementation file" or "message file" for Objective-C. Which name is the right name?
I need to write a tutorials and I have no idea.

Comment: I don't know which name is "right", but "implementation file" sounds good. "Codefile" is misleading since header files also contain code, and "message file" puzzles me—what has it to do with messages? The `.m` extension might stand for "module."

Comment: @Philipp: message file is because in Objective-C the calling of a method is names 'sending a message to an object`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always refer to them as "header files" and "implementation files".

Answer (score 5):

In C++, I always use these terms:
- "Header file" for the .h or .hpp file
- "Source file" for the .cpp or .cxx file
but I don't think there is a real official naming guideline

Answer (score 0):

In the classes I have taken taught with C++ the term for the `.cpp` file that had the function definitions was always the implementation file. The book used was "Big C++" by Horstmann http://www.horstmann.com/bigcpp.html

Answer (score 0):

I would say that "implementation file" or "definition file" are OK. But I don't think they can be considered "official" names.

Answer (score 0):

The clearest way: "*.cpp file*" or "*.c file*"

Comment: And what if the extension is `.cxx`, `.cc` or `.C`?

Comment: Just use ".cxx file" or ".cc file" or whatever it really is. Usually you will only have one of them in each context. Otherwise, e.g. if you use something like "Source file", you will have to deal with ambiguity because for some people Header file is a Source file too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "official" name since the only thing which could make it official is the C++ Standard (which actually puts no meaning at all the file extensions)

I usually call it the "source file" or the "cpp file"